# Meaning of "reach out" in relation to a song

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, deictic-verbs

What does "reach out" mean in this context:

> **A:** Do you think my song will *reach out* to everybody?
>
> **B:** I heard some people say that it's for kids, but that's not true, it
>   *reaches out* to me and I'm 21.

I got this from a video, but can't figure out the meaning. Google said that "reach out" means "to help," but I don't think that's correct in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal  verb here is ***[Reach out to:](https://www.google.it/search?q=rach%20out%20to%20meaning&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=rach%20out%20to%20meaning%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5155j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)*** 
​

> - to try to communicate with a person or a group of people, usually in order to help or involve them:
>
>   - The new mayor is reaching out to the local community to involve them in his plans for the city.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

- Do you think my song will be understood and will be meaningful to everybody?

Comment: Can I just know how did you get "understand"? All I understood from that definition is that a message to people in order to help or involve them.

Comment: @OkamaKsakas - communicate in order to involve...the song lyrics are expected to communicate (be understood), that is to convey their meaning/message to those who listen to them.

Comment: Ohhhh my bad I should've searched for communication definition. Sorry for wasting time. <3

Answer (score 1):

You say "my song". That is an important context.

The [idiomatic choice here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22music%20reaches%20us%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) is not **reach out** to but simply **reach**.

> Do you think the song will reach everyone?

A person listening to the music can say

> The song really reaches out to me.

or

> The song really reaches me.

The phrase **reach out to** expresses something that you as the composer would do (you would reach out to the audience through your music) or something the audience feels about the music (they feel the music reaches out to them).

The composer will know if he or she is trying to reach out to people, and so a question posed by the composer, using **reach out to**, must be about how the *audience* will feel.  The composer could ask:

> Do you think *people will feel* the song is reaching out to them?
>
> Do you think the song will reach people?